# IPython notebook daemon - best way?

Tags: linux, terminal

As of today I use one terminal by server :

- ipython server
- Spark server
- Hadoop server
- etc...
  I end up with seven terminal consoles to manage all these services, which is not that clean.
  I thought to redirect the output or to daemonize these servers with :
- redirection : server > path_to_log 2>&1
- daemonize : server &

but all these services are excepted to be kill via a ctrl-c input. And some are also asking for some questions in the middle. If I do these two options, I will loose these capabilities to 
[1] kill the process (except to send an kill message?) 
[2] answer questions asked sometimes (mainly at service closure : "do you want to save work")

How should I do to limit the number of terminal I have to open ?

Thanks,
romain.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: This is more a hint of a direction to investigate than an actionable solution.  It might be more appropriate as a comment ([from review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/565658)).  Can you expand on this a little?